# How to fetch JSON data dynamically and show in Horizontals scroll view?

Tags: android, json, scrollview

```
      JsonObjectRequest jor = new  JsonObjectRequest(url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()  {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {


                        JSONArray ja = response.getJSONArray("results");

                        ArrayList<Details> myModelList = new ArrayList<Details>();

                        for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jsonObject = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                            mymodel = new Details();
                            mymodel.id = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.optString("id").toString());
                            mymodel.url = jsonObject.getString("resLink");
                            mymodel.resType = jsonObject.getString("resType");
                            mymodel.name = jsonObject.getString("resName");

                            myModelList.add(mymodel);


                            setData(myModelList);

                           ;
                        }
```

how to show these data in horizontal scroll view right now I am  showing these data in the text view.And also, I want to separate these data depending on resTyp.Means restype is video then it will present in Video Horizontal scroll view  similarly for mindmap and so on

```
            private void setData(ArrayList<Details> myModelList) {


    txtview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    txtview2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    txtview3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);


    txtview.setText(mymodel.getUrl());
    txtview2.setText(mymodel.getResType());
    txtview3.setText(mymodel.geturl());


}
```

My JSON is below

```
        {  
      "results":[  
       {  
     "id":37,
     "resType":"Multiple Choice Questions",
     "resLink":"14",
     "resName":"Multiple choice questions",
     "canDelete":false,
     "canEdit":false,
     "canApprove":false
  },
  {  
     "id":38,
     "resType":"Mind Maps",
     "resLink":"upload/7/crops.jpg",
     "resName":"Crops",
     "canDelete":false,
     "canEdit":false,
     "canApprove":false
  },
  {  
     "id":40,
     "resType":"Mind Maps",
     "resLink":"upload/7/dispersal of seeds.tif",
     "resName":"Dispersal of seeds",
     "canDelete":false,
     "canEdit":false,
     "canApprove":false
  },
  {  
     "id":41,
     "resType":"Mind Maps",
     "resLink":"upload/7/reproduction in plants.jpg",
     "resName":"Reproduction in plants",
     "canDelete":false,
     "canEdit":false,
     "canApprove":false
  },
  {  
     "id":42,
     "resType":"Videos",
     "resLink":"HA2yLweR0f8",
     "resName":"Part 1",
     "canDelete":false,
     "canEdit":false,
     "canApprove":false
  },
  {  
     "id":43,
     "resType":"Videos",
     "resLink":"vzduIRvu0qk",
     "resName":"Part 2",
     "canDelete":false,
     "canEdit":false,
     "canApprove":false
  }


  ],
   "status":"OK"
}
```

Comment: So what is your problem now?

Comment: I want to put four horizontal scroll views in one  vertical scroll view

Comment: [this](https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview) might help you

Comment: I tried to make a layout for it with dummy data but the layout does not work and  then I thought to make a Custom 
listview  but all data are coming with no separation .